# Generic variable to store varying levels of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to write a generic centralized null-checker API for pointer type objects. I want to populate a list of my input pointer objects and call the null-checker API to scan through the list and validate if any pointer object is having NULL value. For this, I need to store varying levels of pointers in a single generic variable. How can I do that in C++ ?

```
template<typename type>
bool check(type& t)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename type>
bool check(type* t)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char** doubleCharPointer = NULL;
    char* charPointer = "charPointer";
    doubleCharPointer = &charPointer;
    char** temp = doubleCharPointer;
    char* temp1 = NULL;

    int count = 0;

    if(!check(temp))
    {
        cout << "\nNot a pointer" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    temp1 = *temp;
    count++;

    if(!check(temp1))
    {
        cout << "\nPointer level : " << count << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    count++;

    cout << "\nPointer level : " << count << endl;
}
```

This is my null-checker prototype. It is very static at the moment. But I wanted to extend it to support any level of pointer checking. For that I need "temp" to be able to hold any level of pointer so that I can run an infinite while loop till all the levels of the input pointer is consumed and validated. How can I do that ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a direct solution to this without knowing the exact numbers of levels. Let's say that you can advance level by level checking every level if it's NULL or not, however the main problem is that you don't know how far you must search, so in the end if you just go from address to address you may end up finding a NULL pointer or never ending your verification loop because you don't have a stop condition. 
By doing this you may also access an unallocated memory address which may throw or not an exception, so you can't either use this thrown exception as a stop condition.

Comment: I wanted to achieve this more for debugging purposes and not implementing my project. So, I can have a safe limit of lets say x levels beyond which it will give me a warning that this pointer has unsafe levels and I can have a threshold limit of lets say y levels beyond which it will come out of the loop for that pointer and continuing with the rest of the pointers in the list, giving me a sight-er of the faulty pointer which I can revisit later and redesign so that I do not end up with pointers with more levels than what is reliable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
template<typename T>
bool check_ptr_not_null(const T&)
{
    return true; // not a pointer
}

template<typename T>
bool check_ptr_not_null(T* t)
{
    return (t != nullptr) && check_ptr_not_null(*t);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/yUkgNj)

Comment: I was about to give that as answer, too, but this won't work if the requirement is to store the pointers in some list and defer the check to a later time (though I don't see why one would want to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Do not up-vote this answer (dirty hack)

Expanding on A-B's answer, this is the best I can get to at the moment:

```
template<typename T>
bool notnull(T const *t, int level) {
  while (level-- > 1) {
    if (t == NULL)
      return false;
    t = (T const *)*t;
  }
  return t != NULL;                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Note that this will induce some compiler warnings because of the line `t = (T const *)*t` so I guess this is unsafe. A cleaner way of doing this is just define some macros instead:

```
#define NOTNULL_P1(x) (x != NULL)
#define NOTNULL_P2(x) ((x != NULL) && NOTNULL_P1(*x))
#define NOTNULL_P3(x) ((x != NULL) && NOTNULL_P2(*x))
#define NOTNULL_P4(x) ((x != NULL) && NOTNULL_P3(*x))
#define NOTNULL_P5(x) ((x != NULL) && NOTNULL_P4(*x))
```

Comment: While the approach that uses a C-style cast ist indeed dirty (and it's admirable that you admit that fact), I have no idea why you consider the approach using macros better. Actually, macros are almost always evil, and here the expression `x` is evaluated more than once and its evaluation depends on the operators it uses internally.

Comment: This breaks type safety. Instead of using a template you can just use void pointers.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I did not realize the danger of the macros I presented.